# Changing Legend marker of Devexpress rangebarchart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have created a waterfall chart using devexpress rangebarchart. To give more effect I have overridden
`settings.CustomDrawSeriesPoint = (s, ev`)  for giving different color for bars

1. Blue for normal bars
2. Red for showing decrease
3. Green for showing Increase

But the legend is not sinking with the same. 
Can in any way i could edit the legend markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the it finally.
Here are the steps

1. Added 3 fake series and added it to  chart
2. except these fake series rest are hidden from legend
3. finally overridden CustomDrawSeries as below

> settings.CustomDrawSeries = (s, ev) =>
>
> ```
> {
>         BarDrawOptions drawOptions = (BarDrawOptions)ev.LegendDrawOptions;
>         drawOptions.Color = costIncreaseColor;
>         drawOptions.FillStyle.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
>         drawOptions.Border.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
> };
> ```